# Preinitialize BackgroundAudioPlayer in WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1, background-audio

When I am using the BackgroundAudioPlayer in my Windows Phone 7 application, it takes a lot of time to load the first time I want to play a song. Is there any way of preinitializing the BackgroundAudioPlayer before playing the first track, so that when I start playing, it starts right along? I have googled it, but no luck. I am just using BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance when I e.g. want to play, pause, stop etc an audiotrack. Is there something other i could do to fix this?

Comment: terminology pick: There are no such things as pre-initialization, re-initialization, etc., there is just "initialization".

Comment: I know, but I wanted to put an emphasis on the fact that I want to initialize it before it gets automatically initialized, which is too late. As I have understood, it initializes when needed, right? How can I do this without calling stop, pause etc?

Comment: still picking: How about "explicitly initializing"? Pardon though that I can't help on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just call `BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Stop();` in your App constructor and then discard the first occurance of `UserAction.Stop` in the `OnUserAction` method in your implementation of `AudioPlayerAgent`

Comment: I´ve tried that. Using BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Stop(), it seemed to load 13 of the 18 assemblies, so that was a good improvement. But I would still like to load the 5 remaining before clicking play.

Comment: Is it the assemblies loading that cause the problem? If so you could use Assembly.Load() to pre-load them into your app.

Comment: That didn´t seem to work either. The printline I would like to "bump up" looks like this 'Background Task' (Managed): Loaded 'mscorlib.dll'. The same assembly gets loaded in the UI Task, so how can I explicitly load assemblies that run on a Background task?

Comment: @greve what do do mean by the first occurence? What if user use your app to play music, then quit, then come back to your app ?

Answer (score 0):

This might be looking at this from a simple angle, but could you not call play and then instantly pause it until you are ready to play?? I'm not hugely familiar with the control but looking here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.backgroundaudioplayer_members(v=vs.92).aspx

Upfront you could possibly check BufferingProgress and PlayerState to check when the track is ready to play, and then pause until you're ready to continue.

It's a bit brute force but may work. Worth a try?

Comment: Going to try some of the if checks you recommended to boost it some more. Thanks! More, and other non-brute-force methods are highly appreciated!