# WP7 how to start audio agent process

Tags: windows-phone-7, audio, process, agent

I'm using `BackgroundAudioPlayer` agent for my Windows Phone 7 application. I know that the `AudioPlayer` class lives in another process (let's call it audio agent process).

I heard that "In theory the process for an Audio Player agent could get started and stopped at any time".

Sometimes, when I press play on my UI, the agent process seems to NOT start, and the agent code doesnot receive any `OnUserAction` event. And this cause my application to behave wrongly.

I want the agent process to be ready when I want to play music. How to fix this ?

Comment: Does the same code sometimes work? Or does it never start?

Comment: @keyboardP the problem sometimes happen. It seems that the agent process takes some time to start. And this cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: Unless you can reproduce it, I'm not sure what it could be from the info given. Could it be related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269070/preinitialize-backgroundaudioplayer-in-wp7

Comment: @keyboardP the problem sometimes occur when I open my application. The agent seems to not start. But if I call some UserAction (Play, SkipNext, SkipPrevious, ...) after that, it starts

Comment: What if you force the `Stop` call when the app starts, just to initialize it?

Comment: @keyboardP Sometimes the agent seems to NEVER start, and it cannot receive any UserAction or StateChanged event !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to start playing audio inside dispatcher? Something like next:

> Dispatcher.BeginInvoke( () => {  StartAudioOrSoOn(); });

Try to check examples provided by Microsoft for Windows Phone developers:

[Windows Phone Samples: learn through code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/site/search?query=BackgroundAudioPlayer&f%5B0%5D.Value=BackgroundAudioPlayer%20&f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&ac=8)